# How to Selection number not found in array list using random class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have array list containing numbers

*for example*

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(1);
        numbers.add(54);
        numbers.add(11);
        numbers.add(6);
        numbers.add(8);
        numbers.add(32);
```

I wanna choose new number not found in array list using random class

*my attempts*

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(1);
        numbers.add(54);
        numbers.add(11);
        numbers.add(6);
        numbers.add(8);
        numbers.add(32);
        randomQuestion = new Random().nextInt(numbers.size());
        for (int i : numbers) {
            if (i == randomQuestion) {
                randomQuestion = new Random().nextInt(numbers.size());
            }else{
                numbers.add(randomQuestion);
            }
        }
```

I found many topics but did not work with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare a variable that is the maximum integer to be produced (I use 100) and then in a loop produce random numbers until you have 1 not existing in the list:

```
int max = 100;

ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(54);
numbers.add(11);
numbers.add(6);
numbers.add(8);
numbers.add(32);

int randomQuestion = 0;
boolean exists = false;
do {
    randomQuestion = new Random().nextInt(max) + 1;
    exists = numbers.contains(randomQuestion);
} while(exists);
numbers.add(randomQuestion);

System.out.println(randomQuestion);
```

Be aware that as the list grows, the loop may take longer to finish and if the list is full with all numbers from 1-100 then it will not stop.  
So you must check if all the numbers have been produced, or if the size of the list is < 100 and if so then ask for a new random number.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could pre-generate a list of all numbers from 1 to 100 and then shuffle that list. This functionally gives you a new random number you haven't seen before each time you move through the list, and should be very fast.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(100);

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
    numbers.add(i);
}

Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```